# Cannot run script.sh with ENTRYPOINT Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following script:

```
echo "** Creating data volume."
docker volume create --name sData

echo "** Build the java image that will be used to compile a Java class."
docker build -t bh/java:1.0 ./Java

echo "** Run the Java container to compile a Java class."
docker run --name "java-compile" -v sData:/usr/src/data bh/java:1.0
```

Inside the Java folder, I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:7 AS build-env

# Copy java file to compile and run
COPY ./Main.java /usr/src/myapp/Main.java

WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp

RUN ls -al

# Copy script.sh to root folder
COPY ./script.sh /usr/src/data/script.sh

RUN chmod 777 /usr/src/data/script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/usr/src/data/script.sh"]
```

And the script.sh file:

```
#!bin/sh

# Go to myapp
cd /usr/src/myapp

#echo "Listing all files in directory - myapp"
ls -al

#echo "Compiling the java class"
javac Main.java

# Move the .class file
echo "Moving Main.class to /usr/data/Main.class"
mv /usr/src/myapp/Main.class /usr/src/data/Main.class

cd /usr/src/data

#echo "Listing all files in directory - data"
ls -al
```

When I run the container as mentioned above, I get the following error:

`: not foundta/script.sh: 2: /usr/src/data/script.sh:
's: invalid option -- '
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
: not foundta/script.sh: 4: /usr/src/data/script.sh:
: not foundta/script.sh: 5: /usr/src/data/script.sh:
: not foundta/script.sh: 8: /usr/src/data/script.sh:
: not foundta/script.sh: 11: /usr/src/data/script.sh:
: not foundta/script.sh: 14: /usr/src/data/script.sh:
: not foundta/script.sh: 18: /usr/src/data/script.sh:
: not foundta/script.sh: 20: /usr/src/data/script.sh:`

Comment: `script.sh` starts with `#!bin/sh`. Is it typo here?

Comment: the sData volume will persist whatever `script.sh` you initially added on the first docker run, subsequent changes to `script.sh` won't make it to your running container because sData will be mounted in place of what you're adding to the container. If you think this might be a problem, try deleting, then recreating your volume.

Comment: Hi @Nickolay that' because I am using busybox docker image and not ubuntu or something else. This is a slimmed down version.

Answer (score 1):

another issue might be the placement of "WORKDIR" before COPY command.
As current dir was changed to /usr/src/myapp and copy searching for file in ./ 
If your dockerfile and script is in same folder you can simply call it as "COPY script.sh /usr/src/data"